# Tigris error extracting county data using counties()

Tags: r, maps, tidyverse, r-sf, tigris

I am suddenly getting an error messaging when using `tigris::counties()` even though the same code worked perfectly fine a few weeks ago. Can anyone replicate this error or know of a workaround?

```
require(tigris)
counties_VT <- counties(state="VT",cb=T,class="sf")
```

Error Message:

```
Retrieving data for the year 2020
Error: Cannot open "C:\Users\QSMITH\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYZZH4z"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
In addition: Warning message:
In unzip(file_loc, exdir = tmp) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Thank you!

Comment: Tigris fetches from census.gov, can you access https://www.census.gov/ ? They seem to block requests from some random regions and I've never got through their geoblock from my EU location.  If you need those exact datasets provided by Census, I guess the easy workaround is to use some remote Jupyter or RStudio service to fetch those shp files, i.e. posit.cloud

Comment: This was the issue! I needed to be logged onto my company VPN in order to access any .gov websites. Thank you!